# .prop if statement with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, prop

I'm trying to understand why when I use a .prop() on a radio button for an if statement it will always return false. My goal is to have JS run only if the "#manualOverrideNo"radio button is selected. If anyone could enlighten me I would be very grateful. Here is a fiddle of a snippet of code - http://jsfiddle.net/gv0029/xEfw4/1/ - and here as well:

HTML: 
Manual Overide:

```
<label>No<input type="radio" name="manualOverride" 
id="manualOverrideNo" value="no" checked /></label>

<label>Yes<input type="radio" name="manualOverride" 
id="manualOverrideYes" value="yes" /></label>

<label>Footage:<input type="number" id="footage" 
name="footage" value="" /></label>  

<label>Post Quantity:<input type="postQuantity" 

name="postQuantity" id="postQuantity" value="" /></label>
```

JS:

```
if($('#manualOverrideNo').prop('checked')) {
    //Code For Auto-complete

            //Quantity for Posts
            $('#footage').bind('keypress keydown keyup change', function(){
                var footage = parseFloat($(':input[name="footage"]').val(),10);
                var total = '';
                if(!isNaN(footage)){
                total = Math.ceil(footage /7);
                }
        $(':input[name="postQuantity"]').val(total.toString());
            });
}
```

Thanks again! Y'all are my hero!

Comment: A few tips: `parseFloat` takes no radix. `.toString` is unnecesary as `val()` will do that anyway. If you're on new version of jQuery ditch `bind`, use `on`.

Comment: The code in your jsfiddle seems to work just fine. Can you explain more clearly what's going wrong?

Comment: You are using attr in your jsfiddle

Comment: @A.Wolff yes but changing it to `.prop` makes no difference in this case. It works either way.

Comment: this works fine. Replace attr to prop and I see no issue pertaining to your query.

Comment: @Pointy sure, i was just wondering why? Maybe just a error while saving jsfiddle

Comment: @A.Wolff yes it's one of several mysteries here :)

Comment: He might just wanted documentation and difference between `.attr()` and `prop()` :)

Comment: @DhavalMarthak damn, why i so often misread question?! thx to you

Comment: If that's what he wants, he should just read the first question in the **Related** list, with 704 votes.

Comment: Ok so to recapitulate: "I'm trying to understand why when I use a .prop() on a radio button for an if statement it will always return false"  This is not the case

Comment: Sorry, to clarify I know that the js will auto-complete the Post Quantity field when the button is on "No" for manual override, I am looking to be able to select "Yes" for manual override and have the Javascript NOT auto-complete the math for Post Quantity.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the fiddle and it should work now

http://jsfiddle.net/xEfw4/5/

you needed to have .prop instead of .attr in the fiddle, also, you need to check the value after the action has occurred, not when the page loads.

```
//Code For Auto-complete
//Quantity for Posts
$('#footage').bind('keypress keydown keyup change', function()
{
    if($('#manualOverrideNo').prop('checked')) 
    {
        var footage = parseFloat($(':input[name="footage"]').val(),10);
        var total = '';
        if(!isNaN(footage))
        {
            total = Math.ceil(footage /7);
        }
        $(':input[name="postQuantity"]').val(total.toString());
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/ has info on the difference between attributes and properties.

Comment: OOOOOOhh. Okay that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!